# Trocar um texto por outro utilizando uma string no Menu

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema e não estou encontrando uma solução,

Eu tenho uma string em uma classe `java`, essa string é: **R.string.texto**

Eu vou fazer um menu e colocar nas preferências do aplicativo, para selecionar apenas 1 opção, e cada opção, **vai mudar a string.**

**Exemplo**

Menu com 3 opções

**Opção 1**   R.string.texto_verbo

**Opção 2**   R.string.texto_poesia

**Opção 3**   R.string.texto_frase

Se eu **clicar na opção 2**, a minha string na outra classe `java` vai mudar de texto, para text_poesia.

E eu preciso que esta opção fique armazenada.

Answer (score 0):

Oi

Se eu entendi direito você poderia fazer algo mais ou menos assim

```
public class MinhaClasse {

    private String minhaString;

    public void alteraString(int opcao, String str) {

        if (opcao == 1) {
            minhaString = str.replace(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.')+1), "texto_verbo");
        }

        if (opcao == 2) {
            minhaString = str.replace(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.')+1), "texto_poesia");
        }

        if (opcao == 3) {
            minhaString = str.replace(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('.')+1), "texto_frase");
        }
    }

    public String getMinhaString() {
        return minhaString;
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "R.string.texto";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int opcao;

        System.out.println("Informe a opcao do menu");

        opcao = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("A opcao selecionada foi "+opcao);

        MinhaClasse c = new MinhaClasse();
        c.alteraString(opcao, str);

        System.out.println("String alterada "+c.getMinhaString());

    }

}
```

E na saida teriamos assim

```
Informe a opcao do menu
1
A opcao selecionada foi 1
String alterada R.string.texto_verbo

Informe a opcao do menu
2
A opcao selecionada foi 2
String alterada R.string.texto_poesia

Informe a opcao do menu
3
A opcao selecionada foi 3
String alterada R.string.texto_frase
```

Comment: Sou novo na programação, então preciso tirar algumas dúvidas André. A classe MinhaClasse seria a classe onde vou colocar o menu para escolha, e a classe Main é aquela onde eu já tenho a minha string, certo? E o menu eu devo fazer então na MinhaClasse? Obrigado

Comment: Ola, a classe MinhaClasse tem a responsabilidade de dada uma opção - que vem do menu -  e uma string troca essa string para outro valor de acordo com a sua regra( pode considerar como sua regra de negocio ). A classe Main é apenas para ver se a regra de negocio (que está implementada na classe MinhaClasse) está de acordo com o esperado. A classe Main deve ser trocada pela classe onde voce pega as opções do menu que no caso pode ser por exemplo o click de um botão ou o submit de um formulário, ai depende de como o usuário irá selecionar a opção

Answer (score 0):

Você usa o setText para isso.
exemplo:

```
string texto = 'texto';
int opcao = 1;

if (opçao == 1) {
  texto.setText("seutextoaqui");
}
```

use o evento `Onclick` para fazer instantaneamente.